# Is it possible to retrieve database records inside a Blade View (Laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I know database work shouldn't be done inside the view, but unless there's another way, I think I need to do it.

In my web application, I use the same sidebar for every web page and I want to display records from a table in the sidebar. I don't want to have to retrieve those records in EVERY controller method in my application (as there is a lot).

Is it possible to do this inside a blade view? Or is there another way I should do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach controllers to views! This means anytime the view is called, the underlying controller is also called. This is called a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, can't believe I haven't seen this before. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use should consider view composer https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers